# Pass Variable Name and Value in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I just want to verify that the script I wrote is doing what I think it's doing, and that it's doing it properly.

I wanted to write a script that takes an environment variable and a string value, and then sets that variable to the given value. So I can do something like `setvar BOOST_HOME /home/me/boost/boost_1.52.0` and the script will `export BOOST_HOME=/home/me/boost/boost_1.52.0`

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: setvar VAR VAR_VALUE
function setvar()
{
    VAR=${1}
    VAR_VALUE=${2}
    if [ -d $2 ]
    then
        eval export $VAR=$2
    fi
}
```

This seems to work, at least judging from a echo `echo` tests, but I am still not very comfortable with shell scripting, and would like someone to either verify what I am doing or point out what I am doing wrong / less correct.

Comment: why `{}` bracket only var=$1 like that is enough

Comment: I rather think it should work without the `eval`, and that it would be safer without the `eval` (and I'd put double quotes around the `$2`, but I may be old-fashioned).  You set `VAR_VALUE` but don't use it.

Comment: yep its bad practice to use eval. but if you know you can make it secure, then id dosent matter

Comment: With `export` you need quotes around both `$1` **and** `$2` to be safe.

Comment: @Hackaholic And this script is quite specifically not safe or even attempting to be so. It also falls down on spaces.

Comment: A comment on the purpose of the function itself: if `$2` *isn't* a directory, this function gives no indication that `BOOST_HOME` won't actually be set.

Comment: @Hackaholic, not sure? Habit? Shouldn't be there anyway.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, aye. Fixed

Comment: @chepner, I know, it's something I decided to leave out for brevity's sake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the eval.

```
setvar() {
  if [[ -d $2 ]]; then
    export "$1=$2"
  fi
}
```

Using `[[` instead of `[` avoids the need to quote `$2`, since the bash (and other shell) extension `[[` does not word-split interior parameter expansions. If I'd stuck with the old-fashioned `[ -d "$2" ]`, I would have had to quote the `$2` in case its value included whitespace.

Comment: Might be worth explaining why you need quotes around the variables in the `export` but not in `[[ ]]` since it isn't at all obvious (and in quick testing `export` surprised me in ways I wasn't expecting).

Comment: @EtanReisner: What suprised you about export?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Oh, yeah, that. export/typeset/local/declare (all the same builtin) partially parse the command line; if it is recognizable as an assignment, the part after the `=` is expanded roughly according to [[ rules. If it's not, then regular expansion is followed, and the result is processed. This is particularly wierd when you're using it to assign/declare array elements.

Comment: Right. I mostly understood what must have been going on there it was just surprising. Naively, I'd expected it to not be smart about spaces at all (forcing quotes on the rhs) when that wasn't necessary that was surprising (in the good, and understandable, way) then I tested more and was surprised (in the actually surprised way).